# AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'iter_entry_points' while running Jupyter notebook

Tags: python

When I am running Jupiter notebook it's getting some error.

```
$ jupyter notebook
<....>
AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'iter_entry_points'
```

Also, getting the same error while running python too.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a new version of python 3.7 and solved this issue.